# How to use timers for a Pong game?

Tags: java

I'm remaking my Pong game in Java that I made in Allegro a while back, but I'm not familiar with Java timers, so I don't know how to proceed. I've setup the paddles and the ball, but the ball doesn't move because I have no timer telling it when to do so. I can move the paddles, but that's only because repaint() gets called when I press a key or release a key, and in my paintComponent() method, it updates the positions of the paddles and draws them.

But with the ball, it will need to constantly move, so how do I accomplish this? The most recent version of my project's code can be found on its GitHub project page here: http://www.github.com/packetpirate/Pong

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the answer here: [Java TimerTick event for game loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844794/java-timertick-event-for-game-loop)

On the gameloop, check where the ball is, and where its next position needs to be (i.e. if it hit a paddle or not).