# Separate Logic Thread From Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, thread-safety, logic

***This is the smallest runnable SSCCE***,of my project, that I could implement to show you.

- *I've read that calling the game logic from the Event Dispacth Thread is a bad practice*, how can I separate them, because as you can see  **`update()` and `repaint()` are related into loop**
  and how can I separate code in a pretty way, I'm getting in trouble with this, trying to find out how to do it.
- I've posted a similar question regarding  and I got an answer,that says to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html),but i have huge task to make and as i read `Swing timer` isn't ideal for this scenario.This is the question:

  - [Event Dispatch Thread divided from logic thread,prevent blocking UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758637/event-dispatch-thread-divided-from-logic-thread-prevent-blocking-ui)

***Main class***

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;

    public class Main {

        private static final Main mainFrame = new Main();
        private final JFrame frame;

        private Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static Main getMainFrameInstance() {
        return mainFrame;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            Main.getMainFrameInstance();
            }
        });
        }

    }
```

***MyPanel Class***

```
        import java.awt.Dimension;
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.awt.Graphics2D;
        import java.awt.RenderingHints;
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

        import javax.swing.JPanel;

        public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener,MouseListeners {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            // thread and loop
            private Thread thread;
            private boolean running;
            private int FPS = 60;
            private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;
            private long start;
            private long elapsed;
            private long wait;

            // image
            public BufferedImage image;
            // foo
            private Foo foo;

            private Render render = Render.getRenderManagerInstance();

            public MyPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocus();
            }

            public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            if (thread == null) {
                    addKeyListeners(this);
                    addMouseListener(this);
                thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();
            }
            }


            private  void initGraphic() {
            image = new BufferedImage(700, 700, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            foo = new Foo();
            running = true;

            }

            public void run() {
            initGraphic();

            // loop
            while (running) {
                start = System.nanoTime();
                foo.update();
                repaint();
                elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
                wait = (targetTime - elapsed / 1000000) - 8;
                if (wait <= 0)
                wait = 6;

                try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            }

           public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        ((Graphics2D) graphics).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ((Graphics2D) graphics).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        render.setRenderState((Graphics2D) graphics);
        graphic.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    // clear graphics resources after use them
    graphic2D.dispose();

      }
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                   //code not considerable
          }

          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                       //code not considerable

            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                       //code not considerable

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                      //code not considerable
            }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'EDT'?

Comment: @Illidanek Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do a traditional busy game loop in an event driven environment (which Swing is); that is not a good idea. Consider removing that loop and using a Swing Timer in stead. Or don't use Swing but rather use a Window + Canvas + BufferStrategy to not have an EDT to collide with.

Comment: @Gimby thanks for the comment, can you provide me an example of your' suggestions using above code?

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow? There is a huge chance there are many threads that already cover your needs, especially when you use pretty much outdated APIs such as Swing. Example for swing timer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844794/java-timertick-event-for-game-loop . If you're really doing a game, consider reading into LibGDX though and make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Gimby i know that libgdx is extremely simple to use , but i want to know the fundumental first. i' ve searched a lot of inside stackOverflow i' ve seen also the question that you posted, but, as you can see, my main question is to **divide EDT from logic** ,and in stackOverflow i haven't find yet.

Comment: That's correct - running a huge task on a single pre-defined swing timer thread is not a good idea. You can use the following approach though: launch a new threat (e.g. from EDT or through a regular timer) for your "huge" task. Implement a call back function in EDT. Since that call back function is running in EDT you'll be able to touch GUI and you'll know when the "huge" task is completed. If it sounds reasonable, I could write some code samples.

Comment: @OlegGryb what you described is it a good engineering model? if so, can you show me an example?

Comment: I don't have out of the box example for Swing, but I did use this pattern on Android. I'll need some time to convert it to Swing. The biggest problem will be to make sure that the callback is running on the EDT.

Comment: @OlegGryb this is the point, the logic have to remain standalone,the `repaint()` and all swing stuff have to run  into EDT.

Comment: @oIrC actually if you don't need to touch GUI from the standalone logic then the problem becomes trivial, right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: @OlegGryb i didn't explain well in the last post, the GUI has to print logic update,but them have to remain in two different thread.One of the logic,normal thread,and GUI into EDT.

Comment: "he GUI has to print logic update" - it means that standalone logic does need to touch GUI.

Comment: yes,after consuming his own tasks,the logic has to be refreshed with GUI,anyway,it's all written above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it can look like. You'll need to call the following code somewhere in EDT or through Swing Timer. I'm assuming here that your "huge" task will need to update a text field, but it can be any other UI control as well. All of that, just to demonstrate an idea. Do not treat it as a tested code.

```
//javax.swing.JTextField jfield; The field that needs to be updated. Take it from your Panel
String text = ""; // just a place holder
Object params [] = new Object []{jfield, text}; 
HugeTaskRunner ht = new HugeTaskRunner(params, new CallBack());
```

HugeTaskRunner is derived from AbstractTaskRunner, which looks like follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractTaskRunner extends Thread {


CallBack callBack = null;
Object [] params = new Object[0];

public AbstractTaskRunner (Object [] params, CallBack callBack) {
    this.params = params;
    this.callBack = callBack;

}
public abstract void doTask ();
@Override
public void run() {
    doTask();
    if (callBack != null) {
        callBack.doCall(new Object[]{"DONE"});
    }
}

}
```

HugeTaskRunner:

```
public class HugeTaskRunner extends AbstractTaskRunner {

public HugeTaskRunner(Object[] params, CallBack callBack) {
    super(params, callBack);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void doTask() {
    // HERE YOU'LL HAVE TO DO SOME HUGE TASK ACTIONS
    // THEN YOU'LL NEED TO CALL callBack.doCall(params) to update GUI 
    String newText = "Image #1 has been loaded";
    params[params.length -1] = newText; // assuming that the last param is for updated text
    callBack.doCall(params);

}

}
```

CallBack class:

```
public class CallBack {
public void doCall (Object [] params) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GUIUpdater(params, null));
}
}
```

GUIUpdater class:

```
public class GUIUpdater extends AbstractTaskRunner {

public GUIUpdater(Object[] params, CallBack callBack) {
    super(params, callBack);
}

@Override
public void doTask() {
    // UPDATE YOUR GUI HERE TAKING Swing UI objects from params, e.g.
    if (params.length == 1 && params[0].equals("DONE")) {
        // HUGE TASK IS COMPLETED, DO SOMETHING IF YOU NEED TO
    }
    else if (params.length == 2) { // It's a request to update GUI
        javax.swing.JTextField txt = (javax.swing.JTextField) this.params[0];
        txt.setText((String)this.params[1]);
    }
    else {
        // UNKNOWN REQUEST
    }

}

}
```

Comment: i' ll appreciate your work,really,but i' ve to understand if it is a good modeling of my question.

Comment: Sure, you'll need time to digest it and even more time to test, because as I've mentioned, it's rather a pattern than a tested code that you can just copy/paste, compile and run.

Comment: after 1 day of debugging I managed to make everything work,i made a lot of changes, especially on how to run the logic thread,because as i said i didn't want to start it inside EDT **`and the callback naturally inside`**. so, i called him outside EDT  and in disagreement with comment you posted above : `launch a new threat (e.g. from EDT or through a regular timer)` @Oleg Gryb.

Comment: @oIrC I'm glad it works, but if you don't run your "huge" logic in a separate thread outside of EDT, you'll inevitable slow down or block your GUI. PS. I like questions like yours because they provoke people to create new design patterns. Good luck with  finalizing the solution.