# Event Dispatch Thread divided from logic thread,prevent blocking UI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

how i can separate the logic from the EDT,because as you can see  **logic and render are related into loop**
and how i can separate code in a pretty way, i' m getting in trouble with this,trying to find out how to do.

***Any suggestion/helps/advices?***

**main class**

```
public class MainFrame {

    private static MainFrame mainFrame = null;
    private final JFrame frame;

    private MainFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(new GamePanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static final MainFrame getMainFrameInstance() {
    if (mainFrame == null) {
        mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    }
    return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {// set look and feel to nimbus
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        MainFrame.getMainFrameInstance();
        }
    });
    }

}
```

**gamePanel class on which i start the game loop**

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // thread and loop
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;
    private long start;
    private long elapsed;
    private long wait;

    // image
    public BufferedImage image;
    // foo
    private Foo foo;

    private Render render = Render.getRenderManagerInstance();

    public MyPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    }


    private  void initGraphic() {
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    foo = new Foo();
    running = true;

    }

    public void run() {
    initGraphic();

    // loop
    while (running) {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        foo.update();
        repaint();
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = (targetTime - elapsed / 1000000) - 8;
        if (wait <= 0)
        wait = 6;

        try {
        Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    ((Graphics2D) graphics).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    ((Graphics2D) graphics).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    render.setRenderState((Graphics2D) graphics);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gamePanel should not enter an infinite loop. It should initialize itself and define a method to be called periodically by a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). More generally, whenever you do something periodically, you should not try to keep track of time, but instead define what should be done during a single step and let a timer call you. This makes a much better use of system resources and is a good engineering practice.

Comment: thanks for your answer,it really helps, can you provide me a little example? i' ll appreciate a lot.

Comment: what is not clear to you in the example given in the tutorial ?

Comment: `what is not clear to you in the example given in the tutorial ?` how to use swing timer in my program, i read how works timer,it' s not difficult, but the problem is how to set it into my program.The steps on how to do it. @Zoyd

Comment: Your game panel class should implement the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface. Because of this, it must have a method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. Put `foo.update(); repaint();` into this `actionPerformed`. Remove the loop and instead, build a new timer exactly like in the tutorial. You should be all set.

Comment: initialized by repaint() from Swing Timer

Comment: @mKorbel i know that the solution shown by `Zoyd` should works, but if i want to use two threads one for logic and one for GUI and the GUI must be run into EDT, how i can do? in your opinion?