# How to import .m (Matlab) file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab

I'm trying to use a function from a .m file in a .java file, but it isn't working. This is the error I'm getting.
`"Blocking in Event Dispatch Thread not allowed at com.mathworks.mvm.exec.FutureResult.waitInternal(FutureResult.java:316)"`

```
try {
    MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "p1");
    double out= eng.feval("sih", "C:\\images\\patang\\test.JPG","C:\\images\\patang\\rdkivarnika.JPG");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out);
} catch (EngineException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Logic Thread From Event Dispatch Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744049/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Logic Thread From Event Dispatch Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744049/separate-logic-thread-from-event-dispatch-thread)